# Dissapearing Git Repository in eGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

This is the second time this has happened to me, and I don't know what's happening. I have a Git repository that I manage within Eclipse using eGit. I've been working with this repository steadily for months. Suddenly the repository is no longer available in the "Git Repositories" view. I try to add it back using the "add" utility. The dialog sees the repository, and allows me to select it, but it never adds it back to the view.

The last time this happened I had to complete remove my project, the folder, and add it from remote from scratch. I really don't want to have to do that again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That view should be reading the contents from a file.

`workspace/.metadata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.egit.core.prefs`

Perhaps check its content to see what's in there, perhaps the path that's being stored has been corrupted or something.

Comment: I'm going to check this answer, with the caveat that I also had to rebuild the git config file manually for this repository, and add the path to the .prefs file.